# If (a,b) belong to $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ Then how many of them will satisfy that $[10a+b]/ab$ is an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If $(a,b)$ belong to $\left\{1,2,3\ldots,10\right\}$

Then how many of them will satisfy that $\left[10a+b\right]/ab$ is an integer.

I tried to write it as $10/b+1/a$. Now $b$ must divide $10$ and a should be equal to $1$. but there will be cases which will be integer even if $10/b$ and $1/a$ are not integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We seek the size of the set $$S:=\{(a,b) \in \{1,2,\ldots,10\}^2:10a+b \equiv 0 \pmod {ab}\}.$$

We first observe that $10a+b \equiv 0 \pmod {ab}$ implies $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$, so $a$ divides $b$.  Similarly $b$ divides $10a$.

So, let's check pairs $(a,b)$ which satisfy these conditions:

If $b=1$, then $(1,1) \in S$.

If $b=2$, then $(1,2) \in S$ and $(2,2) \not\in S$.

If $b=3$, then $(3,3) \not\in S$.

If $b=4$, then $(2,4) \in S$ and $(4,4) \not\in S$.

If $b=5$, then $(1,5) \in S$ and $(5,5) \not\in S$.

If $b=6$, then $(3,6) \in S$ and $(6,6) \not\in S$.

If $b=7$, then $(7,7) \not\in S$.

If $b=8$, then $(4,8),(8,8) \not\in S$.

If $b=9$, then $(9,9) \not\in S$.

If $b=10$, then $(1,10) \in S$ and $(2,10), (5,10), (10,10) \not\in S$.

Hence $$S=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,5),(1,10),(2,4),(3,6)\}.$$  So $|S|=6$.

Comment: (Notice that if $a=b$, then $a^2\vert11a$ so $a\vert11$.)

Comment: THIS IS ALMOST TRIAL AND ERROR.so how do we extend it for bigger bumbers..?

Comment: That's impolite; I answered the question you asked (I'm not a mind reader).  Besides, this question asks for solutions to a [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation); it could be that a simple answer doesn't even exist.

Comment: thnx for the answer.!!kudoos for u for that.!!!if it came in an exam then is it correct to write this??